# How extract links from iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example:

iframe.html

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
bla bla bla
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
```

index.html

```
<script>
...
</script>
There are the links from "iframe.html"
http://www.google.com
http://www.yahoo.com
```

Comment: Is index.html and iframe.html in the same domain?

Comment: Does `iframe.html` have the same domain, protocol and port as `index.html`?

Comment: See this answer.

[detect url's in text with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500260/detect-urls-in-text-with-javascript/1500501#1500501)

Comment: @Adeel: That is detecting URLs in strings. The OP wants links in the DOM.

Answer (score 4):

If the domain, protocol and ports match, just use...

```
var links = $('iframe:first').contents()[0].links;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/TkBHr/).

...or without jQuery...

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0],
    doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document; 

var links = doc.links;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/nAWfN/).

This takes advantage of the [`document.links`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.links) property.

Comment: That's cool but he'd still have to iterate that array to display them, likely with `$.each()` so it doesn't really save him much effort over just iterating the anchors directly from the `contents()` selector, right?

Comment: @AlienWebGuy It returns more than `a` elements, and only `a` elements with a `href` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your iframe is on the same domain as your website, and has the id "my_iframe" and you have a div with the id "results", this should work for you:

```
$("#my_iframe").contents().find('a').each({
    $('#results').append($(this).attr('href') + '<br />');
});
```

Take a moment to read up on JQuery's [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) function.

Comment: That way of adding to `#results` is a bit cumbersome. Why not `append()` ?

Comment: Good call, I've only used it to append specific nodes but yea appending a string too makes total sense. Thanks man :)