# Extract any links from the Google search with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How extract links from iframe using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688762/how-extract-links-from-iframe-using-javascript)

`http://www.google.cl/search?q=food` **SOURCE CODE:**

```
<html><head>...<img src="GOOGLE LOGO">...
...
<a href="http://www.SEARCH RESULT 1.com"> RESULT FOR FOOD 1</a>
<a href="http://www.SEARCH RESULT 2.net"> RESULT FOR FOOD 2</a>
<a href="http://www.SEARCH RESULT 3.org"> RESULT FOR FOOD 3</a>
<a href="http://www.SEARCH RESULT 4.com"> RESULT FOR FOOD 4</a>
<a href="http://www.SEARCH RESULT 5.us"> RESULT FOR FOOD 5</a>
...
</html>
```

`experimental_test.html` **OUTPUT:**

> ## the third search result from google is:
>
> http://www.SEARCH RESULT 3.org
>
> ## the fifth search result from google is:
>
> http://www.SEARCH RESULT 5.us

`experimental_test.html` **SUPPOSED source code:**

```
<iframe style="display:none;" src="http://www.google.cl/search?q=food">
<script>
...ge
</script>
```

In other words, I want to extract the specific links,
like the second link in the search.
Without wanting to use PHP

Comment: You can't access cross domain iframe elements! You could build a proxy

Comment: @Waldheinz: good reference, assuming no cross domain.

Comment: @Vlad that question is from the same user, three hours ago :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may not extract something, because you don't have any access to the document inside the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

In short you can't and you shouldn't.

You can't because you're not allowed to use your script to manipulate data from other website.

You shouldn't because it's against Google's TOS to scrape the search results. You should use the [Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html).