# how to check the existance of a link in a text using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [detect url's in text with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500260/detect-urls-in-text-with-javascript)

I want to check a text for the existence of links in it.
want to check for http, https and/or www links.
me tried this.

```
.replace(/(\w+):\/\/[\S]+(\b|$)/gim,'<a href="$&" class="my_link" target="_blank">$&</a>')
        .replace(/([^\/])(www[\S]+(\b|$))/gim,'$1<a href="http://$2" class="my_link" target="_blank">$2</a>');
```

where http and https are working
but www is not working.
i want to get that link in variable too

please help.
thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have a specific question? Any particular JavaScript framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following regular expression

```
(https?://)?www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}\.[a-z]{2,4}
```

Comment: sorry, this one not works. me done this using separate regexps.
`/(https?:\/\/)[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}(\.[a-z]{2,4})*/g` and 
`/www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}(\.[a-z]{2,4})*/g`
thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function checkLink(text) {
    if (text.search('http') > 0 || text.search('https') > 0 || text.search('www.') > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: i think this 1 not gonna work. because if the text contains a word http/https/www. it will appear like link na?