# MSTextView is not detecting some of the URLs

Tags: ios

I added [MSTextView](https://github.com/marksands/MSTextView) in my project. It is working fine in every manner except some of the links e.g. http://www.t-mobileadvantagedirect.com/L.aspx?d=Vb4UseqIl9QYojIAqfjNqw==. I am not having any idea of link regex. Please help me...I finished my whole app, only this issue is bothering me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 190 of `MSTextView.m`, return the following instead:

```
return @"(\\bhttps?:\\/\\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\\/%=~_|])";
```

You also need to specify the `NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive` option when creating the `NSRegularExpression` object.

Also, be a good person, fork the repository, make the changes in your fork and submit a pull request to the original author.

Source of the regular expression: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8943487/350272

Answer (score -1):

I've no idea with the MSTextView, but I can help you! I believe that you've all URLs like in question, and it's not  showing up with the textview, right?

What you've to do is,

Show normal url inside your text with MSTextView, something like,

## Check out my website, here's the link, http://www.t-mobileadvantagedirect.com

okay, now in, `MSTextView`delegate,

You've to check for the URL tapped,

```
- (void) handleURL:(NSURL*)url
{
  if([url.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"http://www.t-mobileadvantagedirect.com"])
  {
        WebViewController *webview = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"http://www.t-mobileadvantagedirect.com/L.aspx?d=Vb4UseqIl9QYojIAqfjNqw=="]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:webview animated:YES];
        [webview release];
  }
}
```

I know this isn't a solution if you've the same domain url for multiple paths!

Comment: -1. This is an incredibly dirty workaround that makes a lot of assumptions. It's much easier to fix the actual problem itself.

Comment: @JustSid, Yes! you're absolutely right. That's why I written I am not really aware of the things used, this can be a trick to overcome the problem. :)