# Regular Expression is not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, match, string-matching

I have a problem with a regular expression, I tested that in some websites and it is working but when I use that regular expression in the project it is not matching with the correct result. the regular expression is the following

```
^(http|https)\://(www\.)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*$
```

I need that kind of regular expression because I need validate something like that:

```
http://www.test.com
https://www.test.com/login
```

the code that I am using is the following

```
var pattern = new RegExp(URL_REGEXP);
if (pattern.test($('input.editValueText').val()))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect URLs in text with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500260/detect-urls-in-text-with-javascript)

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/oM6yW8/1 <-- shows your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to add `+` after the last character class. Your regex would be,

```
^(http|https):\/\/(www\.)[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9])?\/?([a-zA-Z0-9-._\?\,\'\/\+&%\$#\=~]+)*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uK4sT3/4)

Comment: it is the answer, thanks bro. I spent more than 1 hour searching what is wrong. Thanks a lot for your answer