# How to filter URLs in html files?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML file which has URLs in the text. I want to filter URLs like

```
See http://google.com
See the stackover.com
```

I want output like:

```
http://google.com
stackover.com
```

Comment: you mean something like this $("a[href^='http://']");

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect URLs in text with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500260/detect-urls-in-text-with-javascript)

Comment: Please elaborate if the page contains `See the <a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>` or just text

Comment: Yes. It just text only.

Comment: When? Do you want a bookmarklet or do you want a list of links at the end of the current page on load of the page? Anyway, I posted the link to a duplicate that should work for you.

Comment: Sorry, my question is want to filter web links only whatever it's anchor tag applied or not.

Comment: Please add achors too then

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
$('a[href^=http://]').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).text(href);
});
```

Comment: and the one without http? And the ones in the page that are not in links?

Comment: I though the OP wanted to targets external links only. His requirements are quite tedious to understand though.

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

```
<p>http://www.linkedin.com</p>
<div>http://www.twitter.com</div>
<p><a href="http://google.net" />Google</a></p>
<a href="http://www.google.com" />Google</a>
<a href="http://google.net" />Google</a>
<a href="www.google.com" />Google</a>
<a href="http://www.google.org" />Google</a>
<a href="http://www.google.cc" />Google</a>
<a href="http://google.in" />Google</a>
<a href="http://google.edu" />Google</a>
```

### JavaScript

```
$(function(){
  var linkifiedBody = linkify($('body').text());
  linkifiedBody= $('<div></div>').html(linkifiedBody);
  var links = linkifiedBody.find("a[href]");
  links = links.add($("a[href]"));
  links.each(function(){
  var hrefVal = $(this).attr('href');
if(isUrl(hrefVal))
    console.log(hrefVal);
  });
});


function isUrl(s) {
var regexp = /^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?$/i;
return regexp.test(s);
}

function linkify(html) {
  return html.replace(/[^\"]http(.*)\.([a-zA-Z]*)/g, ' <a href="http$1.$2">http$1.$2</a>');
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ld60yz6k/1/)

Comment: It doesn't work. I unable to filter the url links while the HTML file have markup tags between the text. Below I have placed my codings for your reference.

Comment: <div id="textarea">
<textarea id="message" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="button">
<input id="url" type="button" value="Link Extraction"></input>
</div>
<div id="result">
</div>
$(document).ready(function()
   {
    $("input#url").click(function()
          {
     var messagea = $("#message").val();
     var href = $(messagea).filter("a[href*='http://']");
     $("<br>").appendTo(href);
     $("#result").html(href);
   });
   });

Comment: Above example, the code doesn't filter the URL links only. I want to filter the URL links it may appear between the anchor tag or text. 
Below I have placed my code for your reference. It works while doesn't have HTML markup tags in HTML except the anchor tag.

Comment: HTML:
<div id="textarea">
<textarea id="message" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="button">
<input id="url" type="button" value="URL Link Extraction"></input>
</div>
<div id="result">
</div>
jQuery:
$(document).ready(function()
   {
    $("input#url").click(function()
          {
     var messagea = $("#message").val();
     var href = $(messagea).filter("a[href*='http://']");
     $("<br>").appendTo(href);
     $("#result").html(href);
   });
   });

Comment: i have updated my answer and the demo link. however, im still not sure if i understood ur requirement completely. please check if it suffice ur needs.