# How to make link recognized

Tags: javascript, html

I have this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kz935gge/5/ where you can type text and display it like in a chat view.

I would like to make links recognized if it's possible.

For instance, if you type http://www.google.com , you can see that the link isn't recognized.

```
function sendMessage()
{

    var myDate = new Date().toTimeString().replace(/.*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*/, "$1");
    var mm = document.getElementById("myMessage").value;
    var mainDiv = document.getElementById("mainblock");
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode(myDate+"(Me) :"+mm);
    para.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.appendChild(para);
    element.className = 'bubble bubble-alt yellow';
    mainDiv.appendChild(element);    
}
```

Any advice on how can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: What do  you mean with recoginized? Were are the links

Comment: In your chat u mean?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1500501/2976720) answer to detect links with regex

Comment: If you type a link in the input and click on send, you can see that the link isn't clickable...

Comment: Alright, but how  can we test this in the fiddle without the code to make the chat work. Because i looked at the fiddle and i could not see the messages i send

Comment: @DeseaseSparta I cant even see the link

Comment: you have probably Enter the message with the keyboard, you must click the button to send it actually

Comment: I found that out xd i will takje a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex to replace the links:

`.replace(/((?:https?:\/\/|www)[^\s]+)/g,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>")`

Update made here: https://jsfiddle.net/kz935gge/10/

Answer updated to support https

Wanted to update this answer to draw attention to **zzzzBov**'s comment "*this is a very naive regular expression, and fails to properly escape the contents of the link which makes it vulnerable to XSS attacks*"

This is expression is just a starting point, more work is required to make it secure.

Comment: Here is a good place to test and also get a detailed explanation of what this regex string is doing: https://regex101.com/r/cB8cQ8/1

Comment: this is a very naive regular expression, and fails to properly escape the contents of the link which makes it vulnerable to XSS attacks.