# Node.js Bot pulling links out of messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, steam

I'm making a bot in node.js for Discordapp.com that will pull information from a steam profile's xml. It gets the profile links from user messages.

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out a way for my bot to pull the link from messages as they're not consistent.

Messages could look like:

```
http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76562119803123205611 look at that guys
```

or

```
Take a look at this www.steamcommunity.com/id/someusername/
```

or

```
look at this steamcommunity.com/profiles/766119803232061 looks cool right?
```

The only thing consistent in each is "http://steamcommunity.com/" everything else is different. Could I receive some help on how I would pull only that entire link from each message and nothing else?

Comment: use a regex - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500260/detect-urls-in-text-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great place for regular expressions. Here's one that will match any steamcommunity.com URL with `/profiles/` followed by a number and `/id/` followed by characters.

```
var test = "www.steamcommunity.com/id/someusername/";
var regexp = new RegExp("(steamcommunity.com)(/id/[a-z]+|(/profiles/(\d)+))", "i");
var out = test.match(regexp)[0];
```