# check if string contains http url using angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I need to add anchor tag if the string contains "http://" in it,
ex json response:

```
var res =  {status: "ok",activities: [{content: "The icon Canadian. Credit: http://allrecipes.co..."},{content: "The test message"},{content: "The Canadian art http://allrecipes.co"}]}
$scope.posts = res.activities;
```

but, I need to display anchor tag for the http,

I have tried using

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
<span ng-bind="post.content"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You need write regex for this. Post. content is a string.  Not Url.

Comment: @Ved, Will you please share an sample code, I have tried my best. but nothing works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect URLs in text with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500260/detect-urls-in-text-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add html tag inside as a string and use `ng-bind-html` to cmpile the string to dom element

```
{content: "The icon Canadian. Credit: <a href='http://allrecipes.co...'> http://allrecipes.co... </a>"}
```

in the html

```
 <span ng-bind-html="trust(post.content)"></span>
```

Finally add this function

```
 $scope.trust = function(item){
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(item)
 }
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope,$sce){

var res =  {status: "ok",activities: [{content: "The icon Canadian. Credit: <a href='http://allrecipes.co...'> http://allrecipes.co... </a>"},{content: "The test message"},{content: "The Canadian art <a href='http://allrecipes.co'> http://allrecipes.co </a>"}]}
$scope.posts = res.activities;

$scope.trust = function(item){
  return $sce.trustAsHtml(item)
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
<span ng-bind-html="trust(post.content)"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need the anchor tag for the below response
`var res =  {status: "ok",activities: [{content: "The icon Canadian. Credit: http://allrecipes.co..."},{content: "The test message"},{content: "The Canadian art http://allrecipes.co"}]}`