# Js - regex for finding urls in body text not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to implement regex that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500260/detect-urls-in-text-with-javascript). I would like to find any `http`, `https` or web `a tags` and then just add target="blank" to them. So, the code looks like this:

```
const urlRegex = /(((https?:\/\/)|(www\.))[^\s]+)/g;

        return this.node.body.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
            return `${url}" target="blank">`;
        })
```

And if I get a text like this:

```
<p>
  <a href='www.norden.org'>Nordens</a>
</p>
<p>
  <figure>
    <img src='http://tornado-node.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Ove-Hansen.jpg' alt=' Styreleder Ove Hansen. Foto: Arne Walderhaug' />   

    <figcaption>Ove Hansen, styreleder i Norden</figcaption>
  </figure>
</p>
<p>
  <a href='http://norden.org/documents.html'>norden.org</a>
</p>
```

This is the result from the above function:

```
<p>
  <a href='<a href=\"www.norden.org'>Nordens</a>
</p>
<p>
   <figure>
     <img\" target=\"blank\"> src='<a href=\"http://tornado-node.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Ove-Hansen.jpg'\" target=\"blank\"> alt=' Styreleder Leif-Ove Hansen. Foto: Arne Walderhaug' />
     <figcaption>Ove Hansen, styreleder i Norden</figcaption>
    </figure>
</p>
<p>
   <a href='<a href=\"http://norden.org/documents.html'>norden.org</a></p>\" target=\"blank\">"
```

What is the correct way to implement this?

**Update**

I am also trying with finding the href in the text like this:

```
    let str   = this.node.body;
    const regex = /(href=\')([^\']*)(\')/g;

    if (str.match(regex)) {
      for(let i = 0; i < str.match(regex).length; i++) {
        let url = str.match(regex)[i] + ' target="_blank"';
      }
    }
```

And that gives me an array with strings that match href but and I add `target="_blank"` to it, but how can I replace that now with inside the text that I am checking?

Comment: It's "_blank" with underscore, this is not a solution to your problem, obviously :)

Comment: Also, what's the point of looking for "http" and "https" without anchor tag? Adding target doesn't make sense without it.

Comment: Why do you use regex. You could use jquery easily

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with HTML, try to avoid parsing string. You can try something like this:

#### Logic:

- Create a dummy element to work on. This will be an in-memory element and will not be rendered.
- Set html string as its innerHTML.
- Fetch any element that can have url in it like `a` or `img`.
- Loop on this list and check for regex validity on necessary attribute.
- If satisfied, add attribute.

```js
function getUpdatedHTMLString(htmlString){
  var urlRegex = /(((https?:\/\/)|(www\.))[^\s]+)/g;
  var dummy = document.createElement('div');
  dummy.innerHTML = htmlString;
  
  var list = dummy.querySelectorAll('a, img');
  for(var i = 0; i< list.length; i++) {
    var href = list[i].getAttribute('href');
    var src = list[i].getAttribute('src');
    if (urlRegex.test(src) || urlRegex.test(href)) {
      list[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    }
  }
  
  return dummy.innerHTML;
}

var str = "<p>" +
"<a href='www.norden.org'>Nordens</a>" +
"</p>" +
"<p>" +
"<figure>" +
"<img src='http://tornado-node.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Ove-Hansen.jpg' alt=' Styreleder Ove Hansen. Foto: Arne Walderhaug' />" +
"<figcaption>Ove Hansen, styreleder i Norden</figcaption>" +
"</figure>" +
"</p>" +
"<p>" +
"<a href='http://norden.org/documents.html'>norden.org</a>" +
"</p>";

console.log(getUpdatedHTMLString(str));
```

```html
<p>
  <a href='www.norden.org'>Nordens</a>
</p>
<p>
  <figure>
    <img src='http://tornado-node.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Ove-Hansen.jpg' alt=' Styreleder Ove Hansen. Foto: Arne Walderhaug' />

    <figcaption>Ove Hansen, styreleder i Norden</figcaption>
  </figure>
</p>
<p>
  <a href='http://norden.org/documents.html'>norden.org</a>
</p>
```

Comment: But, I need to get a tags from a body text that I am passing to my vue template, not from the whole page

Comment: In that case, you can create a in-memory element and set your `body.text` as its html. Then instead of document, use this variable. Point is, HTML string will become pain, if you try to manipulate it as a string using regex.

Comment: @Leff one workaround can be search for the string using regex. Then look for first value of `>` and add your attribute here

Comment: Could you post an example of that, if it is not a problem, thanks in advance!

Comment: I have updated my question with something I would like to implement just don't know how to replace the matches in the string.