# Add target blank to links if it has http or https

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find in a text all links that have http or https and add target blank to them it they exist with this code:

```
    const text   = this.node.body;
    const regex = /https?:\/\//i;
    let newStr = text.replace(regex, '$& target="_blank"');

    return newStr;
```

But, it doesn't work, the links that have http or https are not getting target blank. What is the correct way of doing this?
This is the example text:

```
<p><a href='www.link.com'>Link</a></p><p><div><img src='http://image.jpg' /></div></p><p><a href='http://link.html'>link</a></p>
```

And this is the result of the code:

```
<p><a href='www.link.com'>Link</a></p><p><div><img src='http:// target="_blank"/image.jpg' /></div></p><p><a href='http://link.html'>link</a></p>
```

Comment: What is the context? Is it in node (server) code?

Comment: Please show us an example of the text you expect to parse

Comment: Why does this look similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469541/js-regex-for-finding-urls-in-body-text-not-working/46469723#46469723

Comment: node is the object, that has text

Comment: @Marco As said in my answer in associated link, when dealing with HTML string, using regex and string manipulation will only make things worse. Using an in-memory element will help and ease manipulation

Comment: So you don't want http://link.html -> http:// target="_blank"/link.html?

Comment: Please include output showing what you want.

Comment: Your question makes reference to `href='www.link.com'` but consider that this link will redirect within your website (it will redirect to something like `http://www.yourdomain.com/www.link.com`), so maybe that isn't the best example to use.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="http"]').forEach(function(e) {
  e.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: Please refer to link under comments. This solution will not help

Comment: I see your edit. This was an answer to your original question but I will see if I can edit to fit your new parameters.

Comment: @Rajesh in your edit you reference a link that points to "www.link.com". Note that this is not an offsite link as it will send users to http://yoursite.com/www.link.com

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. What edit are you talking about?

Comment: @Rajesh no worries, I was referring to your most recent edit here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46474353/revisions

Comment: @Rajesh My mistake! I incorrectly thought you were OP. I still believe that matching a relative anchor is probably not what the asker wants but I will let them clarify that if it is the case.