# Regex URL detection javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I am using this regex to detect URLs in a text string:

```
/(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}(\.[a-z]{2,6}|:[0-9]{3,4})\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)/gi
```

Combined with this function to replace the detected strings with links:

```
function linkify(text) {
    return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
        return "<a href=" + url + ">" + url + "</a>";
    });
}
```

Both found here: [Detect URLs in text with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500260/detect-urls-in-text-with-javascript)

This is working for the majority of links, however links such as `www.fatsoma.com/flatline-cardiff` and
`tickets.partyforthepeople.org/events/3633` are detected, but link to nowhere, adding the local path in front of the detected link e.g `http://127.0.0.1:8000/filelocation/tickets.partyforthepeople.org/events/3633`

Is this to do with the absence of a protocol such as Https at the beginning of the link?

Comment: Browsers have done endless damage by deciding to hide the protocol prefix in the location bar.. A valid full absolute URL has to start with `http://`, `https://` or similar.

Comment: The regex really looks funky, I’m pretty sure it will deliver both false positives and false negatives. Also, based on context, there may be some decoding to do to get an actual URL. And handling of relative URL composition. And your replacement is missing quotes as well as escaping.

Comment: I noticed that your function doesn't quote the href value. Better is: `return <a href="${url}">${url}</a>` (put the text within backticks, I can't use them in a comment)

Comment: @jcaron Yeah, it's giving me some false positives on words separated by ellipses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this to do with the absence of a protocol such as Https at the beginning of the link?

Yes.

Try to add a protocol if not present:

```
function linkify(text) {
    return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
        if (url.indexOf('http://') === 0 || url.indexOf('https://') === 0) {
             return "<a href='" + url + "'>" + url + "</a>";
        }
        return "<a href='//"+url+"'>"+url+"</a>";
    });
}
```

Comment: This fixed the issue with those links, thanks!

The regex is throwing false positives though, so I'll have to work on that.