# How find link in text and replace that to anchor?

Tags: javascript

I have string in my text selector

```
<p> Lorem Ipsum http:facebook.com</p>
```

I need get result

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum <a href="http//:facebook.com">http:facebook.com</a></p>
```

How i can make that? It's need for http, www and https

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect URLs in text with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500260/detect-urls-in-text-with-javascript)

Comment: `http:facebook.com` is not a valid url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a id for your paragraph tag. and Get text of your paragraph tag in jquery and replace it with the link by following script

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var mystring = $('#paragraphId').text();
 var url   = 'http';
 var urlend   = '.com';
 var pos1 = mystring.indexOf(url);
 var pos2 = mystring.indexOf(urlend);
 var urlstring =  mystring.substring(pos1,pos2+4);
 var substring1 = mystring.substring(0,pos1);
 var substring2 = mystring.substring(pos2+4);
 $('#paragraphId').text(substring1);
 $('#paragraphId').append($("<a href='"+urlstring+"'></a>").text(urlstring));
 $('#paragraphId').append(substring2);
});
```

```html
<p id="paragraphId"> Lorem Ipsum http:facebook.com Lorem Ipsum</p>
```