# access first regex matching group inside replace function

Tags: javascript, regex

this might be easy but I just can´t see the forest because of trees. Given is following function:

```js
const urlify = text => {   
    let urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)(<\/td>)/g;      
    return text.replace(urlRegex, function(text) {
            return '<a href="' + text + '">' + text + '</a>';
        })
     }
      
    alert(urlify('<td>http://test.com</td>'))
```

more or less like the function from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1500501/1474777).

The regex replace() function currently gets the whole match. Hence the link contains the closing `</td>`. How would I just access the first capture group `urlRegex.exec(text)[1]` inside the function?

Comment: This is covered by [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capture groups get passed to your function as additional arguments after the first one:

```js
const urlify = text => {
  let urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)(<\/td>)/g;
  return text.replace(urlRegex, function(_, text) 
// Ignoring the first argument ----------^^
    return '<a href="' + text + '">' + text + '</a>';
  })
}

console.log(urlify('<td>http://test.com</td>'))
```

But you don't need a function for this, you can use tokens in the replacement string:

```js
const urlify = text => {
  let urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)(<\/td>)/g;
  return text.replace(urlRegex, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
}

console.log(urlify('<td>http://test.com</td>'))
```

More [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).