# url detect regex

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I want to detect urls in a text and i have achieved that using the following regex

```
const urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
```

This detects the urls when starting with `https` or `http`. But i want to detect a url starting with `www` as well. How can i modify this regex to detect urls starting with `www` also?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url

Comment: www. is not a valid url without a browsing context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect URLs in text with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500260/detect-urls-in-text-with-javascript)

Comment: please give typical input and output

Answer (score 2):

One option is to alternate between `https?://` and `www.`. Also note that `[^\s]` should probably be avoided - better to use `\S`, which will match all non-whitespace characters, which is easier to read:

```
/(?:https?:\/\/|www\.)\S+/
```

https://regex101.com/r/nZhWZY/1