# JS RegEx for matching a complete URL

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I'm trying to match a URL in a string of text and I'm using this regex to search for a URL :

```
/\b(https?:\/\/.*?\.[a-z]{2,4}\b)/g
```

The problem is, it only ever matches the protocol and domain, and nothing else that follows.

Example :

```
let regEx = /\b(https?:\/\/.*?\.[a-z]{2,4}\b)/g;
let str = 'some text https://website.com/sH6Sd2x some more text';

console.log(str.match(regEx));
```

Returns :

```
https://website.com
```

How would I alter the regex so it will return the full URL?

```
https://website.com/sH6Sd2x
```

Working Demo :

```js
let regEx = /\b(https?:\/\/.*?\.[a-z]{2,4}\b)/g;
let str = 'some text https://website.com/sH6Sd2x some more text';
console.log(str.match(regEx));
```

Comment: Your regexp ends with `\.{a-z]{2,4}\b`, so that will only match the top-level domain part of the URL.

Comment: @Barmar, yes thanks, I'm aware of that. My question was how to alter the regex to include the rest?

Comment: A usual URL extraction pattern assumes there are no whitespaces after protocol. Try just `/\bhttps?:\/\/\S+\b/g`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/btltNG/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yep that's it, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it stops there is that your expression ends with `\.[a-z]{2,4}` which I guess is intended to match the top level domain (`.com`, `.net`, `uk` etc). After that it stops matching.

The solution: add `\/[^\s]*` to the expression. This matches a further slash and zero or more non-whitespace characters.

Note that `\S` (with capital S) is equivalent to `[^\s]` (with lowercase s), so use what you like best.

Demo:

```js
let regEx = /\b(https?:\/\/.*?\.[a-z]{2,4}\/[^\s]*\b)/g;
let str = 'some text https://website.com/sH6Sd2x some more text';

console.log(str.match(regEx));
```

You might even shorten it further if you realize that URLs never contain whitespace, and matching the domain explicitly is not needed, or worse it may even cause trouble (e.g. `.museum` is also a valid TLD, but you exclude it).

Enhanced version (shorter regex and more accurate):

```js
let regEx = /\b(https?:\/\/\S*\b)/g;
let str = 'some text https://website.com/sH6Sd2x some more text';

console.log(str.match(regEx));
```

Comment: Yep this is exatly what I was looking for. Thank you so much @Peter!

Comment: Ended up adapting yours and creating this one: `\b((https?:\/\/)?(www)?\S*\.\S*\b)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/D1LPH6/1)

Answer (score -1):

Since the regexp ends with `\.[a-z]{2,4}\b`, it only matches up to the top-level domain part of the hostname in the URL. You need to match the rest of the URL after that. This matches any non-whitespace characters after that:

```
let regEx = /\bhttps?:\/\/.*?\.[a-z]{2,4}\b\S*/g;
```

See [Detect URLs in text with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500260/detect-urls-in-text-with-javascript/1500501#1500501) for more complete solutions to matching URLs.