# URL in a tag concatenating in website URL when i click on it

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-parsing

i am getting anchor tag in `stringHTML` in API response and parsing it using [react-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser)
which is working fine. The problem is when I click on the anchor tag URL does append in website URL which makes it wrong URL. You can see in the below image.

[image]

So my question is what can i do to avoid this behavior? If URL contains `https://www.facebook.com` then it is working fine but if it contains `www.facebook.com` then it append in website url.

Live Code: https://testonqa.vonza.net/scheduling/faheem-saleem

just select any slot and you will redirect to next screen where you will see description in bottom of form.

StringHtml markup in API

```
description: "<p><a href="www.facebook.com" rel="noopener noreferrer"
```

My code to parse it

```
 <span class="text-muted">
    {ReactHtmlParser(eventDescription)}
 </span>
```

Comment: www.facebook.com is not a valid URL. You need to add protocol - `https://` or the link becomes relative to the page you are on. This is just how the interwebs work.

Voting to close as _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: Add `href="https://www.facebook.com"` instead of `href="www.facebook.com"`.

Comment: @mplungjan 
@ModiMohammed User is entering url in text editor `react-quil` on admin site. how can i add protocol myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [Detect URLs in text with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500260/detect-urls-in-text-with-javascript)

```js
function urlify(text) {
    var urlRegex = /(((https?:\/\/)|(www\.))[^\s]+)/g;
    return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url,b,c) {
        return url2 = (c == 'www.') ?  'https://' +url : url;
    }) 
}

console.log(urlify(`description: "<p><a href="www.facebook.com" rel="noopener noreferrer"`))
```

or just give an error message if there is a link and the link href does not start with `https?\:\/\/`