# javascript regex for wss, ws http and https

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to retrieve those URls from a string using regex in JavaScript

Here is an example string:

```
"Hello everyone! please join us at: https://oursite.com/. and 
please visit our courses websites: http://courseone.com.eu & http://coursetwo.us. 
For prod use websocket with this url: wss://localhost:4500/websocket/. and 
for staging use this url: ws://localhost:4500/websocket".
```

Now I want to extract these URls from the above string:

Like this:

```
https://oursite.com/
http://courseone.com.eu
http://coursetwo.us
wss://localhost:4500/websocket/
ws://localhost:4500/websocket
```

Now I followed this regex given in [Detect URLs in text with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500260/detect-urls-in-text-with-javascript)

```
/(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
```

But it is not properly working for me since I have **wss** and **ws** URls aswell

Can anyone help me with the regex?

Comment: So just `(http|ws)s?` instead of `https?`

Comment: @Bergi Can you post the final solution as answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this part `[^\s]+` in your pattern matches too much.

Depending on the formats and the characters that you want to allow in the links, you can get the desired result from the question by matching optional non whitespace characters and then end on not a `.` or `"`

```
\b(?:http|ws)s?:\/\/\S*[^\s."]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kwpelx/1)

```js
const regex = /\b(?:http|ws)s?:\/\/\S*[^\s."]/g;
const s = `"Hello everyone! please join us at: https://oursite.com/. and 
please visit our courses websites: http://courseone.com.eu & http://coursetwo.us. 
    For prod use websocket with this url: wss://localhost:4500/websocket/. and 
    for staging use this url: ws://localhost:4500/websocket".`

console.log(s.match(regex));
```

Or end the match on a word character followed by an optional forward slash:

```
\b(?:http|ws)s?:\/\/\S*\w\/?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wnugxU/1)

Comment: when i say www.google.com it doesnt work

Comment: @StormTrooper That is correct right? Is does not start with http:// or ws://

Comment: @StormTrooper You could start with `www.` as an alternative `\b(?:(?:http|ws)s?:\/\/(?:www\.)?|www\.)\S*[^\s."]` See https://regex101.com/r/l5hD2I/1

Comment: whatsapp is doing some sort of trick with urls it even know when we type google.com or abc.net it doesn’t work woth garbage urls like godhd.hdh