# how to correctly render text that contains a link, like to links ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, hyperlink, refactoring

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

I receive text in the following format

```
text: "hello here is the link https://www.hello.com see you soon"
```

my problem and the next one, so I receive a text and inside there is a link, when I have a link in this text I would simply like to be able to click on it

here I already have something that works very well

my I'm really not a fan of how it's done, I would like to have your opinion on a possible refacto or another way of doing it surely simpler? more js?

```
function hello({ text }) {

const urlRegex =
    /(https?|Https?):\/\/[^\s/$.?#]\S*|www\.[^\s/$.?#]\S*|ftp:\/\/[^\s/$.?#]\S*|[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}/g;

const Click = ({ text }) => {

    const elements = [];
    let lastIndex = 0;
    let match;

    while ((match = urlRegex.exec(text)) !== null) {
        const prefix = text.substring(lastIndex, match.index);
        const url = match[0];

        if (prefix) {
            elements.push(prefix);
        }

        elements.push(
            <a
                key={match.index}
                href={url}
                target="_blank"
                rel="noopener noreferrer"
                style={{ textDecoration: "underline" }}
            >
                {url}
            </a>
        );

        lastIndex = urlRegex.lastIndex;
    }

    const suffix = text.substring(lastIndex);
    if (suffix) {
        elements.push(suffix);
    }

    return <>{elements}</>;
};

return (
    <p>
        <Click text={text} />
    </p>
);
```

}

Comment: Think you can use this logic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500260/detect-urls-in-text-with-javascript