# Regular expression for URL validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having form which takes url as input..I want to validate it using javascript and regular expression..

it should accept

- `www.google.com`
- `google.com`
- `http://google.com`

Please suggest me a regular expression and total code if possible for validation of url...
i tried lotta url given on many forums..but couldn't get appropriate answer..
thanks in advance

Comment: There is a closed question which addresses this. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226505/question-about-url-validation-with-regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226505/question-about-url-validation-with-regex)

Comment: What would not be valid?

Comment: Have a look at [all of these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+regex+validate+URL) and especially [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410311/regular-expression-for-url-validation-in-javascript) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058138/is-it-safe-to-validate-a-url-with-a-regexp) one.

Comment: Your second example is going to ruin your regex requirements; you're going to be left with something like `/\w\.\w/`

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
^(http\://)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?$
```

this will support

- http://google.com
- http://www.google.com
- www.google.com
- google.com

Comment: The code above will fail a lot of tests for edge cases. When detecting URLs, it's ALWAYS better to rely on a specialized library. [Here's why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21925491/1269037).

Answer (score 0):

You can test it easily with jQuery :

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/url.

Answer (score 0):

try dis

```
url_reg = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
```

Comment: "dis" code above will fail a lot of tests for edge cases. When detecting URLs, it's ALWAYS better to rely on a specialized library. [Here's why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21925491/1269037).

Answer (score 0):

This one would be fine, `(http|https|)(://|)([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?`

Try it here. works fine - http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Comment: The code above will fail a lot of tests for edge cases. When detecting URLs, it's ALWAYS better to rely on a specialized library. [Here's why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21925491/1269037).