# Is it Possible to Validate URL in JS

Tags: javascript, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression for URL validation (in JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410311/regular-expression-for-url-validation-in-javascript)
>   [Regular expression for URL validation in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450989/regular-expression-for-url-validation-in-javascript)

Is it possible to validate any type of URL including sub components and parameters with in  JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

yes it is try

```
function validateURL(textval) {
      var urlregex = new RegExp(
            "^(http|https|ftp)\://([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9\.&amp;%\$\-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$");
      return urlregex.test(textval);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

```
function isUrl(s) {
    var regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
    return regexp.test(s);
}
```