# javascript fetch last url without prefix

Tags: javascript, regex, mootools

I am looking to detect last url from text using **javascript** or **mootools**. Url canbe without **prefix/scheme**

I am working on URL auto sense like Facebook. Where a user may give an URL www.example.com or with http://www.example.com either of them should be detected by JavaScript. see stackoverflow detected URL that included with scheme without URL scheme it couldn't detect URL. In my case I need both.

**Here is some text**

```
'http://www.example.com www.example2.com'
```

Now I want **www.example2.com** It will be better if I get full array containing both **http://www.example.com** and **www.example2.com**

I searched a lot but couldn't find solution.
Most close to my requirements were [Question about URL Validation with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226505/question-about-url-validation-with-regex/226709#226709) and [How do I extract a URL from plain text using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504853/how-do-i-extract-a-url-from-plain-text-using-jquery)

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by combing info in these 2 links:
[How do I extract a URL from plain text using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504853/how-do-i-extract-a-url-from-plain-text-using-jquery)
[Detect URLs in text with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500260/detect-urls-in-text-with-javascript)

We can get this:
http://jsfiddle.net/qQwGA/1/

If I understand what you're trying to do, this should cover it.

Comment: Pyro979 thanks it seems to work let me check a little bit more. Once again many many thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

**REGEX**

```
/([^:\/?# ]+:)?(\/\/[^\/?# ]*)?[^?# ]+(\?[^# ]*)?(#\S*)?/gi
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
var str = 'http://www.example.com www.example2.com scheme://username:password@domain:port/path?query_string#fragment_id';
var t = str.match(/([^:\/?# ]+:)?(\/\/[^\/?# ]*)?[^?# ]+(\?[^# ]*)?(#\S*)?/gi);

/* 
   t contains : 
   [ 
     "http://www.example.com",
     "www.example2.com",
     "scheme://username:password@domain:port/path?query_string#fragment_id"
   ]
*/
```

**DEMO**
>http://jsfiddle.net/wvYTd/

**DISCUSSION**

- This regex will find any substring that **looks like** an URL in an input string.
- No validation is performed on any URL found. For instance, if the input string is `3aBadScheme://hostname`, the regex will detect it as an URL. In this example, `3aBadScheme` is invalid since a scheme MUST start with a letter.

  Excerpt from [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.1)

> (...)
> Scheme names consist of a sequence of characters beginning with a letter and followed by any combination of letters, digits, plus ("+"), period ("."), or hyphen ("-").
> (...)

Comment: I bet that was just a sample url ;))

Comment: And customizing the answer for her need will be a good exercide for OP :)

Comment: I agree with @MichalKlouda. This is just a sample text please keep in mind. I have given references also which were very close to my necessity. thanks.

Comment: I have updated the regex and the jsfiddle link. Again, if you have more url samples valid in your context, send them.

Comment: @Stephan thanks. Let me explain me a bit more. I am working on URL auto sense like Facebook. Where a user may give an URL as I said www.example.com or with http://www.example.com either of them should be detected by JavaScript.

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA Check my new answer. It may now fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Given your input string, I think you just want to split it using spaces as separator?
`.split(' ')` ?

Comment: Savageman this is just a sample please keep in mind. I have given references also which were very close to my necessity. thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question with more details. I can't understand better than I answered...